# Equal height of UICollectionViewCell's and UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How am I supposed to set the height of the cells in UICollectionView equal to the height of whatever the collection view is? The code below doesn't work because the collection views height is not known at this point it seems since the auto layout is messing with the properties at this stage. It causes the cells height to be higher than the actual collection view.

***I will add 300 in bounty to an answer that solves this!***

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

       return CGSize(width: 100, height: collectionView.frame.size.height)
    }
```

> 2015-12-16 18:43:53.643 My-app[1055:434762] the behavior of the enter
>   code hereUICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because: 2015-12-16
>   18:43:53.643 My-app[1055:434762] the item height must be less than the
>   height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom
>   values, minus the content insets top and bottom values. 2015-12-16
>   18:43:53.643 My-app[1055:434762] Please check the values return by the
>   delegate. 2015-12-16 18:43:53.644 My-app[1055:434762] The relevant
>   UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is , and it is attached to ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {3087, 307}>
>   collection view layout: .
>   2015-12-16 18:43:53.644 My-app[1055:434762] Make a symbolic breakpoint
>   at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the
>   debugger.

**Solution that works based on hannads suggestion. If there are better ways please let me know**

Made a property with a property observer.

```
var myCollectionViewHeight: CGFloat = 0.0 {
    didSet {
        if myCollectionViewHeight != oldValue {
            myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.prepareLayout()
        }
    }
}
```

Override this method (it is called multiple times)

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    myCollectionViewHeight = myCollectionView.bounds.size.height
}
```

Then I have this in my delegate:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {            
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: myCollectionViewHeight)
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. First add a global variable in the view controller which will be used to store the height of the collection view. In the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method, set this variable to the height of the collectionView, and if it changed, call a method to invalidate the `UICollectionView` layout

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

Which will call the method to set sizes of the collectionView cells, and in that method, set the height of the cell to the global variable holding the height of the collectionView.

**Note**: currently on my mobile and did not test this code. I might have missed something.

Comment: This is not far away from working. I will update my question with the full answer.

Comment: Do note however that this will layout the collection view once in the beginning, and once after you invalidate the layout. Not the most efficient solution, but the one I know. Will be waiting for your update.

Comment: @LuckyLuke You mentioned that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called multiple times. I think that `didSet` is called each time `myCollectionViewHeight` is set, even if it was the same value. Could you add an if statement to check if `myCollectionViewHeight` is not equal to `myCollectionView.bounds.size.height` before setting it? That might help.

Comment: Yeah, I could do that. Did set property observer will be called each time viewDidLayoutSubviews with the current setup. I will change to what you suggest. It won't change the fact that viewDidLayoutSubviews is invoked multiple times, but I guess that is correct because of auto layout is adjusting or something like that.

Comment: @LuckyLuke you said that is it not far from working. Is it still giving you a problem?

Comment: It works now. But without this line `myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.prepareLayout()` it will log the error/warning that I posted originally.

Comment: @LuckyLuke Since no one else replied since then, are you going to wait some more, or can you accept this answer?

Answer (score 11):

You try set this code to your `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Setting this property in the Storyboard also helps with the offset. Otherwise any UICollectionView is pushed down when you put it into a UINavigationController. Uncheck "Adjust Scroll View Insets"

Comment: `'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: Use UIScrollView's contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior instead`

Answer (score 6):

I had been struggling with this issue for over a week and finally found an answer that worked for my specific case. My issue was a result of 1) loading remote images in the UICollectionViewCell's image, and 2) having an estimated cell size that was larger than what I set manually on the sizeForItemAt of the collection view layout.

[image]

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
}
```

I was able to solve by reducing the cell size on the storyboard to an amount lower than my cell's size, and I also set "Estimate Size" to "None" (this last part is probably enough)

Comment: Bless you. Your answer is why I can still meet my deadline this month.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have to set `collectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize` to an explicit value (which has its height <= collection view's height) instead of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize`.

The `UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize` results a default 50pt by 50pt cell size, which is higher than my collection view. In this case, UIKit refuses to do any layout work, despite that the actual cell size after self-sizing calculation will be smaller.

```
// horizontally scrollable collection view

private var viewHeight: CGFloat?

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    
    if viewHeight != view.bounds.height {
        viewHeight = view.bounds.height
        layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: viewHeight!)
        layout.invalidateLayout()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because I had pinned my `UICollectionView` to the bottom of a `UITableViewCell` without giving the `collectionView` a height.

After making a few network requests and then calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` in the `UIViewController`, I got the same error message in the log.

I managed to resolve it by breaking the bottom constraint and giving the `UICollectionView` a fixed height.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with this solution:

1. Cell size is equal collectionView size

[image]
2. Change in storyboard "Inset from:" from Safe Area to Content Inset

[image]

3. Change "Content Insets" to Never
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well and i was able to solve it by subtracting the relevant `sectionInsets`.  Once you subtract the insets that aren't considered in the `.size.height` property it accepts the height.

Inside `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` you need to subtract the section inset dimensions...

```
  let sectionInset = self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.sectionInset
  let heightToSubtract = sectionInset!.top + sectionInset!.bottom

  return CGSize(width: 100.0, height: (self.collectionView?.bounds.height)! - heightToSubtract)
```

NOTE: I am force unwrapping the optionals here but to be safe you might want to check them

Comment: But the thing is that I have set the insets to 0 with the delegates methods. This shouldn't be necassary then.

Comment: @LuckyLuke I'm assuming that you have the contentInset set to 0 as well?  And you've printed out these values and can confirm everything is 0?  I dunno then, because something is telling your height to be greater than what the collectionView.bounds.height is being set and hard to tell without looking at the project

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I add collectionview to tableviewcell， and collectionview item height is equal to tableviewcell height. when change tableviewcellheiht, i get this warning. 
to solve this , try this code

```
  if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        _collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
    } else {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be easily solved by setting the collectionViewLayout itemSize property inside your viewdidload:

```
collectionViewLayout.itemSize = .init(width: 80, height: 80)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep "Estimated Size" to "Automatic" and add this to your `UIViewController` to make sure the `UICollectionView` layout get updated after the content view got rendered:

```swift
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  self.recentAthletesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```